# When are there infinite stationary points?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Say we are given:

$$f(x_1,x_2) = \alpha (x_1^2+x_2^2) + \beta x_1x_2 + x_1 + x_2$$

then $$\nabla f = \langle f_{x_1}(x_1,x_2), f_{x_2}(x_1,x_2) \rangle = 0$$
for stationary points.

which will give us: $$\nabla f = \langle (2x_1\alpha + \beta x_2 + 1), (2x_2 \alpha + \beta x_1 + 1) \rangle = 0 $$
I need to find

a) $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there is no stationary points.

b) "..." exactly $1$ SP, and its a global strict minimum

c) "..." infinite SP, and all of them global minimizers.

For b) and c) this requires that $\nabla ^2 f(x) $ is positive definite, and positive semidefinite for all SP, respectively.

**However for what conditions imposed on $\alpha ,\space \beta$ will there be infinite Stationary points?**

Also am I correct for $a) $ in saying $\alpha, \beta = 0$ since then $\nabla f \neq 0$? Or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: The function is: $f(x_1,x_2)+\alpha (x_1^2+x_2^2)+\beta x_1x_2+x_1+x_2 $?

Comment: yes that is correct, fixed typo.

Answer (score 0):

Critical points solve the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \alpha & \beta \\
\beta &2 \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
A necessary condition to have infinitely many critical points is that the matrix of this system be singular, i.e. $4\alpha^2=\beta^2$. Can you go on with this suggestion?

Comment: Right. Well the hessian $\nabla ^2 f$ is just this system $= 0$. For us to have global minimums for the infinite SPs, does that not occur for $$ 4 \alpha^2 - \beta^2 \geq 0$$ ? Otherwise it would be strict global minimums. But then this contradicts the existence of infinite stationary points, which requires $4\alpha^2 = \beta^2$